# Adding a movieclip in each square of my calendar (AS3)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've got a calendar with squares in which each date is written:

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();
var row:Number = 0;
var moonNum:Number;
var holder_txt:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
addChild(holder_txt);
holder_txt.x = 35;
holder_txt.y = 10;
startDay -= 1;

    for (var t:int = 0; t < getDays(myDate); t++) {
    myArray[t] = (t+1);
    var textNum:String = myArray[t];
    import box;
    import moonPhase;
    var square:MovieClip = new box();
    var moon:MovieClip = new moonPhase();
    holder_txt.addChild(square);
    square.name = textNum
        moonNum= calculateMoonPhase(myDate.fullYear, myDate.month,t+1);
    
    square.texter.text = textNum +" "+ moonNum;
    
    
    square.x = (startDay) *75
    square.y = (row+1)*65
    startDay++;
        if(startDay >= 7){
            startDay = 0;
            row++;
```

I've got a function that calculate the moonPhase for everyday.

```
 moonNum= calculateMoonPhase(myDate.fullYear, myDate.month,t+1);
```

It results as a number (between 0 and 8).

I've got movieClip of a moon with 8 frames (new moon, full moon... etc.).

I'd like to add the movieClip of the moon on each square with the corresponding frame number.

```
moonClip.gotoAndStop(moonNum);
```

I've added each moonNum to each square day:

```
square.texter.text = textNum +" "+ moonNum;
```

But I've no idea how to add movieclips to each square day...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to add **moonPhase** in the class **box** directly. So for each box that you copied, you have an instance of moon in it to.

But, in your sample code, you can add moon to the square directly to.

```
square.addChild(moon);
```